# How to check if the HTML selection option contains any values in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Order to stop multiple requests to server incase if the HTML Selection option is not empty

Could anybody please let me know how to check if the HTML Select is not empty

This is my HTML

```html
<select name="" id="SCname">
     <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Select Screen</option>
</select>
```

```js
var json = {
        "employees": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Anna",
                "lastName": "Smith"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Peter",
                "lastName": "Jones"
            }
        ]
};
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < json.employees.length; i++) {
    var firstName = json.employees[i].firstName;    
    var lastName = json.employees[i].lastName;
    html += '<option value="'+firstName+'">'+lastName+'</option>';
}
$('#SCname').append(html);
$('#SCname').show();
```

Could anybody please tell me how to check if this is empty or not ??

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b84kn/).

Comment: Why not check `if ($("#SCname").val()!=="") { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

To determine the number of options in the `SELECT`, using javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById('SCname').options.length == 1 ){  // 1 because it looks like you automatically added 1 via HTML
}
```

or jQuery:

```
if ($('#SCname option').length == 1) {...}
```

It's not entirely clear if you asking how to determine the current selected option or the number of options...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, **use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method**:

```
if ($("#SCname").val() !== "") { 
  // ... The selection is not empty.
}
```

*Note: this requires that you're "empty" option has an empty value: `value=""`.*

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/b84kn/8/)

---

If you *also* want to **check if `option` elements exist** in the `select` menu:

```
var mySelect = $("#SCname");
if (mySelect.val()!=="" && mySelect.find("option").length>0) { 
  // ... The selection is _not_ empty.
}
```

Comment: It IS working -- the "Select Screen" option is selected.

Comment: you don't want to use this to determine if the list is empty, this code would determine if there is a selected option.

Comment: @TMcKeown, OP says nothing about a "list." The question says to check if the "select is not empty." I'm understanding that as some value is selected. OP, do you want to know if there are any options at all or if an option is currently selected?

Comment: the `select` being empty is not very clear...  OP why don't make it MORE CLEAR

Comment: please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b84kn/4/ , it doesn't have any values but its not printing empty

Comment: That's because you didn't specify a value for the option; thus, it defaults to the contents. Just add `value=""` as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/b84kn/6/ .

Comment: "failing" how? Please clarify.

Comment: Means it has got a value but it is printing empty know .

Comment: Because the value is empty... Isn't that what you want? Your question says: "Could anybody please let me know how to check if the HTML Select is not empty?" **That is how you check if an HTML `select` menu is not empty.**

Comment: Ok , i really apologize for this . I don't know that this has got different meaning .

Comment: No worries, bud. What are you trying to do? Please clarify in your question. : )

Comment: Thanks , i want to check if there any values in the option .

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what you mean. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery `size()` method on the select element option which will return the number of elements (This number should be greater than **1** since you are holding a default element):

```js
if ($('#SCname option').size() > 1)
{
  // Do some stuff
}
```

---

Maybe I misuderstood your logic but, I would tell that since you are dynamically appending option elements, why not just check the lenght of `employees` object before doing any additional processing:

```js
var html = '';
if (json.employees.length > 0) // Check your array size
{
  for (var i = 0; i < json.employees.length; i++) 
  { 
    var firstName = json.employees[i].firstName;
    var lastName = json.employees[i].lastName; html += ''+lastName+''; 
  } 
  $('#SCname').append(html); 
  $('#SCname').show();
}
```